# Adding new WHERE statements to a query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I'm doing a foreach loop in Laravel Eloquent where in each foreach I am in need of adding a new Where statement to a SQL query. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
            $list = Records::whereNull('deleted_at');

            foreach ($search as $keyword) 
            {
                $list = $list->orWhere("title", 'like', '%'.$restriction.'%');
            }
            $list = $list->get();
```

This should then return:

```
$list = Records::whereNull('deleted_at')->orWhere("title", 'like', '%'.$restriction[0].'%')->orWhere("title", 'like', '%'.$restriction[1].'%')->get();
```

But it just seems to return all records. Do note that I am only adding whereNull('deleted_at') in there because otherwise I have orWhere without having another where statement.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$keyword` in place of `$restriction`

```
     $list = Records::whereNull('deleted_at');

        foreach ($search as $keyword) 
        {
            $list = $list->orWhere("title", 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
        }
        $list = $list->get();
```